# Select in Hibernate Query language with join

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have two tables : `session_start` and `session_end`.

Columns of `session_start` table are

```
session_id 
user_id
```

Columns of `session_end` table are

```
session_end_id
session_id 
session_met
```

Now from `user_id`, i want to get all `session_met` for `user`. What can be the hibernate query for it?

Answer (score 1):

```
class SessionStart {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column  
  private pid;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private User user; 

}

class SessionEnd {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column  
  private pid;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private SessionStart start;

  @Column
  private String met;

}
```

HQL

```
select end.met 
  from SessionEnd end inner join SessionStart start 
  where start.user.pid = :userPid
```

But better, in my opinion, of course, to have one table for the session start and end.

```
class Session {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column  
  private pid;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private User user;

  @Column
  private String met; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need your hibernate mappings to create a HQL for it. Otherwise it will be plain SQL like:

```
select e.session_met
       from session_start s
       join session_end e on s.session_id = e.session_id
where  s.user_id = ?
```

for HQL you need to join on property, like

```
join s.property to session_end on session_start object
```